# how can save data return by URL from android

Tags: c#, api, rest, model-view-controller

I have started to learn about restful APIs and need some guidance for motivation. Thanks 
I am trying to store data into SQL server which is fetched by URL from Android. I am using a restful API created in visual studio using MVC4 and also using entity framework. 
The below URL is used for getting the data

http://localhost/finalWebAPI/api/Location/ahmad%6078.000%6089.000

I want to save the values after ahmad that split the string. 
The below code is the data model in model class

```
 public class locationdata
{
    public static AndroidDBEntities2 db = new AndroidDBEntities2();


    public static string locationcordinates(string name){
        if (name != null) {
            string[] str = name.Split('%');
            string name1 = str[0];
            string id1 = str[1];
            string id2 = str[2];

            user u = (from u1 in db.users
                      where u1.user_name ==name1

                      select u1).First();

            u.lag = id1;
            u.lng = id2;
             db.SaveChanges()  ;


        }

        return null;

}
```

Here is the controller

```
     public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{

       var reg1 = locationdata.locationcordinates(id);




 //   var employees = locationdata.UpdateEmployee(name,l);
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, reg1);
    return response;
}
```

The route is below

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

please see the below link at first :

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection

By default web API routing to api/{ControllerNam} and get HTTP method to choose correct action in controller.
this URL (localhost/finalWebAPI/api/Location/ahmad%6078.000%6089.000) do not point to any controller by default asp.net webapi routing. yo must change it to localhost/api/{ControllerNam}/6078.000%6089.000